# What is pg_class in Postgres and how to see it using pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin, system-views

I'm new to Postgresql and I just saw my friends query on a cakePhp controller that call 'pq_class'. I tried to look up to my PostgreSQL database and find out what's inside using pgAgmin4.

Unfortunately, I can't see any table name with 'pg_class'. I tried to google and find these pages :

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-class.html

[postgreSQL - pg_class question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2658245/postgresql-pg-class-question)

But I am still confused about `pg_class`. Is there any good or real explanation about pg_class and how to see it using pgAdmin4 without using any query (just right click -> view data)

Comment: What's unclear about the description from your first link: "*pg_class catalogs tables and most everything else that has columns or is otherwise similar to a table.*"

Comment: *good or real explanation* all of sources postgresql you can see in documentation.. If you are not understand read carefully documentation and do researching again..

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name, what catalogs means there ? why need to catalog tables ?. Sorry, my background is mysql, so can't imagine pg_class. Thank you

Comment: @dwir182 sure, thank you

Comment: "catalogs tables" = "stores information about tables"

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name and others - late to party, but it would be easy to guess if it was called `pg_objects` or `pg_tables`. If there is a history or reason to call it specifically `pg_class`, some one can comment.

Comment: @samshers: well, there is [a view](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/view-pg-tables.html) named `pg_tables`. The name `pg_class` is indeed historical as Postgres has object oriented roots and thus those were treated as "classes" internally.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pg_class` is an internal system table that stores information about tables (and similar objects") available in the database. Every database product has such a [collection of system tables](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalogs.html) (and views) that it maintains.

You can (and in most cases should) use the views from the [`information_schema`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/information-schema.html) if you want to see information about tables, columns, views and other database objects.

Answer (score 0):

You can get details from information_schema on pgadmin like this.

`
SELECT * FROM information_schema.columns;

select * from information_schema.tables`